# Can you help me convert this curl command to NSURLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl, nsurlrequest

I want to convert the `curl` command:

```
$curl -s -w '\nLookup time:\t%{time_namelookup}\nConnect time:\t%{time_connect}' -o /dev/null http://www.example.com
```

to a `NSURLRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, NSURLConnection and NSURLSession don't provide any mechanism for finding out when the DNS lookup finishes, much less any way to obtain statistics on the lookup time or the connect time, so there's not really a direct translation.

The closest you can get would be:

- Store the value of [NSDate date].
- Use CFHost to do the lookup yourself.
- Request [NSDate date] again and compare the two dates to get the lookup duration.
- Issue the request using either NSURLConnection/NSURLSession (the DNS lookup should be cached).
- Specify a delegate class for the NSURLConnection or NSURLSession.
- In that delegate class, implement either **URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:** (for NSURLSession) or connection:didReceiveResponse: (for NSURLConnection).
- In that method, request [NSDate date] again, and compare that with the date when the lookup finished.
- Use **NSString stringWithFormat** to construct the output string.